# LINQ to SQL equivalent for XML file persistence

Tags: xml, linq-to-sql, file, object, save

Microsoft has made saving objects very easy with their LINQ to SQL mapping.

However, I would sometimes like something a little more lightweight, i.e. the ability to save objects to a file when an application closes, and read them back in again. XML seems like a natural data format rather than inventing a new data format. (Of course, one could argue that XML is the new ascii, and we still have the problem of defining the data schema etc. ..).

Is there a predefined method of doing this, or am I going to have to manually figure out an XML data format and write routines to read/write them, i.e. by constructing a DOM equivalent and then saving as XML?

Comment: Look into XML Serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

Comment: @Allen - you should put this in as an answer as its a relatively straightforward means to do exactly what Larry wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about working with your data in [DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) and [DataTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), etc - then [serializing them as XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28VS.85%29.aspx)?